# Centering ul across a container

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time centering 3 li elements across the width of a container.  I'm working on a responsive layout, so I don't want to use a fixed width on any elements.  Here is a fiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/vzNbr/

Notice if you extend the output screen that is aligning to the left of the container instead of centering.  CSS is simply:

```
.container {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#about {
background-color: #ebebeb;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#about ul.info {
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}

#about ul.info li {
width: 20%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 1.5em;
font-size: .8em;
}
```

An ScreenShot:[image]

Comment: Your `li`s have 20% width of their parent; and there are 3 `li`s making up to 60%; so the container `ul` have 40% space left; naturally that 40% (or less) space is keeping your layout non-centered; I think you have to make sure your `li` s make up to 100% of their container;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out `float:left`, set your `ul` at `display:table` and the `li` as `display:table-cell`. Here's your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vzNbr/1/

Comment: Nice solution. And change the margin to padding.

Answer (score 1):

Try losing the float and changing display to table-cell:

```
#about ul.info li {
width: 20%;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 1.5em;
font-size: .8em;
}
```

you'll probably have to tweak the padding etc. but it should do the trick.

Comment: *sigh* would have been nice to be the accepted answer, as it was posted first, but that's life...

Answer (score 1):

See if thats what you need http://jsfiddle.net/vzNbr/2/

I put some colors just to see it clearly, but, you only need to change

```
#about ul.info li {
    margin: 1.5em;
}
```

to this

```
#about ul.info li {
    margin:0 6.6666665%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why it's floating leftish, but this seems to keep it more centered, though I doubt it's the best solution.

```
    #about {
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    left:20%;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I knew I could be tweaking the container and positions around but the container will be used through other elements and wanted to try and avoid that, Thanks tho man :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 columns, their width should be 33,33%.
To not let the margin add extra width to this 33%, you can use padding and box-sizing: border-box.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/n8gkK/

```
#about ul.info li {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.5em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to center an element, use this code snippet:
in this case you have a container that should fit its children total sizes.if you don't know its size,check it in firebug or chrome inspect-element and use the below.

```
.centered {
  position: based on your choice;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -(container-element_height/2);
  margin-left: -(container-element_width/2);
}
```

if your container element doesn't have a known size, you should rule your layout like a table.